# Having trouble with \blindtext

Tags: packages, blindtext

When using `\usepackage{blindtext}` vimtex throwing me a Compilation failed.

My setup is vim + vimtex and as compiler I am using latexmk.

PS: I had prior to that problems with `\usepackage[enlgish]{babel}` as well, but then I just moved it to the top just under the `\documentclass` this fixed that issue, but with `blindtext` it seems not to work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which tex distribution do you use? Have you installed the complete or only a basic version? Could simply be that you have `blindtext` not installed ...

Comment: Can you try to add the language as a class option? Then it is used by babel and blindtext. And I hope enlgish is a typo in your question and you use english in your document. If not, that language is undefined,

Comment: Thanks for the response. It might be, that blindtext is not installed. I have tried using english as a classoption for the document and it seems to work. There is no compile error.
If blindtext is not installed, how can I get this package (I am new to LaTeX :/)?
Oh and yes I typed it off the screen "enligish" is not a language for sure. :)

Comment: Oh hi, thanks for sticking with me. I have researched a little bit and I seems like vimtex (this is a plugin for vim to use LaTeX) uses TeXLive. I have to ask though what this logfile is you talk about. What file format does this file have?